# grant permission to all operations with database

Tags: sql-server

How to grant select/update/insert/execute permission to all tables/procedures in database? Create role?

Because I want to have guests(all select permissions to some tables), users(only select,update,insert permissions to tables) and administrators(all permissions to all objects in database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 1) Useful  when there are large no. of users.
`GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE on SCHEMA::SchemaName to Principal` --often DBO for Schema

For the Principal, it is FAR preferrable to use a role and not a single user,  Unless you just have a few users, it usually simplifies your management.

Now, if a utility schema is added, the user has no access to the data, but, if a table is added to the SchemaName schema, they automatically have access.

Approach 2) useful in case of few users.
adding the user to `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles if you need access to all tables in the database. Its short & simple.

```
USE [DBName]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'UserName'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'UserName'
```

Reference : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/1489337c-56c9-4bb8-9875-3a75be7596be

Answer (score 3):

I would create roles. Or specifically one role because there's already roles for what you describe as "guests" (i.e. the public role) and administrators (i.e. db_owner role). But let's make it real.

```
create role [Users];

grant select on tbl_1, tbl2, tbl3 to [public];
grant select, insert, update, delete to [Users];

exec sp_addrolemember @membername = 'yourdomain\Users', @rolename='Users'
exec sp_addrolemember @membername = 'yourdomain\Admins', @rolename='db_owner'
--no need to add people to public; everyone's a member by default
```

Comment: I don't understand. if I want to add user as guest I need to write `exec sp_addrolemember 'public','Joe'`?(for admin - 'db_owner')?

Comment: For public, no; everyone is a member of the public role by default (though you'll have to add them as a user in the database). But yes, for your admin users, you'd add them to the db_owner role. Hopefully you have an AD group that you can add as a user rather than having to admin individuals.