# Restricting access to one database on SQL Server 2012 when connecting with integrated security

Tags: sql-server, tomcat

I use Tomcat7 and SQL Server 2012.

I have two databases running on the SQL Server, one called `mydb1` and one called `mydb2`. Both databases are practically identical, but the latter is used for testing.

Here are the `web.xml` connection strings

```
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb1" type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" initialSize="30"
            maxActive="100"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=mydb1;integratedSecurity=true;"
            />

<Resource name="jdbc/mydb2" type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" initialSize="30"
            maxActive="100"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=mydb2;integratedSecurity=true;"
            />
```

Since I am connecting with integratedSecurity, is there any way I can restrict the first connection from looking at the second database and vice versa.

In other words: When connecting with the first connection, can I prevent the code `SELECT * from mydb2.USERS` from being run. Similarly, when connecting with the second connection, can I prevent the code `SELECT * from mydb1.USERS` from being run.

Comment: What you're looking for entails setting permissions on your database. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761164/grant-permission-to-all-operations-with-database](Please look at this article.)

Comment: I'm not sure that this article refers to connections with `integratedSecurity`...

Comment: integratedSecurity just means you're logging in to the SQL Server with a windows username, instead of a DB username.  Both types of logins can be managed (i.e. add/remove permissions) on the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure: No. The only thing you can authenticate with [SSPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (ie. 'windows Authentication) is the identity of the process connecting. If the two connections connect from the same process then they are indistinguishable. If they are indistinguishable you cannot use GRANT/DENY/REVOKE.

If you are looking for something that is not secure (eg. prevent *accidental* use of the wrong database) then you can rely on [`APP_NAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189770.aspx). Emphasis on not-secure, the app_name is just a setting in the connection string can and be spoofed by anyone.

It is somehow unusual to share test and production database host (will running test impact production result timing?) and even more so is sharing the test and production *client* (your Tomcat).